# How does Facebook convert fbclid to _fbc

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need the _fbc value but not from the cookie, so I need a way to convert the fbclid to the _fbc value and store it somewhere else to trigger the API conversion, but due to the coming changes to iOS I can no longer rely on the cookie so what is fbclid using to encrypt to the _fbc?

I've been trying to research on how to get the value but I have not found anything yet.

Comment: Why do you think there is a way to convert between them?

Comment: you are actually right @WizKid, I found in the documentation that the _fbp is created instead of encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Facebook dev docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/parameters/fbp-and-fbc

If you don't have the pixel installed or the _fbc cookie isn't available, then the fbc value is a combination of the version, subdomain index, the UNIX timestamp in milliseconds, and the fbclid value:

fb.1.timestamp.fbclid-value